# RobotFramework combine test template with variables and other keywords

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to use test [Template] as part of a testcase.

Below Testcase i want to use "Set Variable" and "Get Current Date", but robot doesn't recognize the keywords.

I don't want the test [Template] to be seperated from the testcase.
Secondly I want to use the [Template] as a Keyword, because i have different testcases and sets of data.
So the [Arguments] from the Keywords are dynamically. With the goal to use this Template as a parameterized Keyword.

I hope my wishes a clear.

Is this possible or is there a better way to resolve this.

```
***** Test Cases *****

RUN Example test with template
  ${current_date_yyyy-mm-dd}=      Get Current Date      result_format=%Y-%m-%d   
  ${xxx}     Set Variable    tmpvalue
  [Template]    Generate xxx message 
            1    2    3    4
            3    3    3    3
```

I tried the [setup] variant, but I don't like this solution, because its seperated from the testcase.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using a user keyword that encapsulates both the "Set Variable" and "Get Current Date" keywords.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
RUN Example test with template
    ${xxx}     Set Variable    tmpvalue
    Generate xxx message with current date

*** Keywords ***
Generate xxx message with current date
    ${current_date_yyyy-mm-dd}=      Get Current Date      result_format=%Y-%m-%d   
    [Template]    Generate xxx message 
        1    2    3    4
        3    3    3    3
```

"RUN Example test with template" calls the user keyword "Generate xxx message with current date," which includes both the "Set Variable" and "Get Current Date" keywords as well as the actual test template "Generate xxx message." This way, you can keep the related keywords and the template within the same test case.

Comment: This solution suites if the [Template] is used with static data. I want to use the [Template] with dynamic data. I don't want to copy the [Template] and reuse it for other testcases. I didn't specify my problem en preferred solution correctly. My bad..